# How to make two projects depend on each others in maven

Tags: maven, websocket, java-ee-7

I work in i a project where i have 3 modules, client/core module, EJB module and WEB module.
The EJB and WEB modules depends on core module and WEB module depends on EJB module. Every thing works fine until here.

Now i added a Websocket endpoint i the WEB module and since my logic code is in the EJB module, i will need to call Websocket endpoint from my EJB module so that i can push data to client.
Adding WEB module as a dependency to EJB module causes -as expected- a :

```
The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference ERROR
```

Any idea to how efficiently resolve this issue ? -without moving the Websocket endpoint to the EJB module which seems illogical-

Comment: The better question is:  Why do you want to call your Webendpoint from your EJB module?

Comment: My Websocket endpoint contains a List of currents sessions so that i can send messages to a particular client. and the logic that triggers the send is in my EJB module

Comment: I am going to move this List into the EJB module ! thats surly gonna solve my problem.